# Bootstrap 5.1 scrollpy .active not working on .list-group-item

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Quick and simple question, I cannot get bootstrap scrollpy working correctly even if I only copy paste the example from documentation !

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/scrollspy/

Anchor link work as expected of course but .active class for the list item while scrolling doesn't change, it only apply permanently on page load on the last item without any reason.

I'm not adding code since I only copied/pasted the documentation example's.

Regarding css/js import I've changed their position in all possible cases, it doesn't change anything.

Does anyone know what's happening ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

First, you add bootstrap.min.css inside the head tag then added popper.min.js and bootstrap.min.js script tag inside the body tag. This time you copy-paste the code from the documentation. In the meantime, you add CSS height and overflow-y: scroll. Please check the code below.

```css
.scroll {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="scroll-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <div id="list-example" class="list-group">
              <a
                class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
                href="#list-item-1"
                >Item 1</a
              >
              <a
                class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
                href="#list-item-2"
                >Item 2</a
              >
              <a
                class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
                href="#list-item-3"
                >Item 3</a
              >
              <a
                class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
                href="#list-item-4"
                >Item 4</a
              >
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8">
            <div
              data-bs-spy="scroll"
              data-bs-target="#list-example"
              data-bs-offset="0"
              class="scrollspy-example scroll"
              tabindex="0"
            >
              <h4 id="list-item-1">Item 1</h4>
              <p>
                This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note
                that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation
                link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component
                example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize
                the scrolling and highlighting. This is some placeholder content
                for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page,
                the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated
                throughout the component example. We keep adding some more
                example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
              </p>
              <h4 id="list-item-2">Item 2</h4>
              <p>
                This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note
                that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation
                link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component
                example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize
                the scrolling and highlighting. This is some placeholder content
                for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page,
                the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated
                throughout the component example. We keep adding some more
                example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
              </p>
              <h4 id="list-item-3">Item 3</h4>
              <p>
                This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note
                that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation
                link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component
                example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize
                the scrolling and highlighting. This is some placeholder content
                for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page,
                the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated
                throughout the component example. We keep adding some more
                example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
              </p>
              <h4 id="list-item-4">Item 4</h4>
              <p>
                This is some placeholder content for the scrollspy page. Note
                that as you scroll down the page, the appropriate navigation
                link is highlighted. It's repeated throughout the component
                example. We keep adding some more example copy here to emphasize
                the scrolling and highlighting. This is some placeholder content
                for the scrollspy page. Note that as you scroll down the page,
                the appropriate navigation link is highlighted. It's repeated
                throughout the component example. We keep adding some more
                example copy here to emphasize the scrolling and highlighting.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your message ! The problem is solved, I was just missing the data-bs-spy="scroll" tag attribute I added to the body. Now it is working BUT I don't know what this attribute is and what it does since the documentation does not really get into the details about those requirements. On the other hand I didn't have to addd the css property : overflow-y: scroll. Maybe it is already activated by default on the concerned div.